# CI pipeline in multi stage environments amongst many Scrum teams

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, devops, scrum

I am looking for a solution for 20 scrum teams, on how to push code in different environments:

- Dev (where developers can code and run unit tests)
- SIT (integration with stubbed services)
- QA (where QA testing happens, with real integration points, no stubs, currently maintained by a separate team, so that they keep track of what's going in)
- Stage (similar to Live, with sensitive data, maintained by a separate team)
- Live (that's the live game)

The sticky point here is that many teams would try to push to SIT and things could take time to deploy, and potential bottlenecks could be caused. Also, we need to ensure that our code works well with real integration points (QA env).
With respect to Scrum also, when should we call a user story Done, when we push to SIT, or QA?

I'm sure this has been asked before but couldn't find the exact terminology, feel free to point me to.

**EDIT**: it's a brand new product, clean slate, no code or pipelines as of yet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about workplace software development, rather than about programming within this site's scope.

Answer (score 1):

OK, your exact question was: When do you call a User Story done? In Scrum, it is Done when it is potentially shippable, so in your setup: Stage.

Now, I expect that will sounds unrealistic to you and your team. And that is because you have a number of snags in your process that you'll have to solve to really accomplish CI/CD and to have potentially releasable code in a sprint:

1. Continuous Integration. I don't mean the server and platform/tool you use. I mean actually integrating everyone's code on every checkin. If you've got 20 teams who don't do this today, they aren't going to suddenly start tomorrow. As soon as you try, you're going to run into all kinds of practice, process, and architectural challenges. You'll need to work through those in order to achieve this. My best suggestion is start by having teams in common areas continuously integrate with each other, then start breaking down the barriers between those groups. If even that is too much, maybe just have each individual team integrate with each other multiple times a day as a start. Honestly, the rest of the steps aren't very relevant if you haven't got this down.
2. Testing is something that happens elsewhere. It's happening at a different stage, in a different environment, and probably with a different team. This is a problem for two reasons. If testing happens after the story is called done, it reenforces the idea that the job of the team is to write code, not create working, usable functionality. Second, those bug reports are going to come back, then stuff that was done and integrated has to be reworked and redone and integrated. If integration was painful before, this just adds a multiplier onto it.
3. Do you have cross-functional teams working on increments of value? It's a bit of a stretch for me to guess here, but service stubs and difficult integrations are often signs that different teams are working on different components. This creates a lot of opportunity for misalignment that can exacerbate your challenges.
4. Ok, last one. You have whole teams maintaining environments. That's a big red flag. That means your system is either extremely complicated or that people are leaving a lot of loose ends or both. If you hav to build whole teams around synchronizing other teams, you may be putting a band-aid on your problem. Your environment should be predictable and stable. That means that most tasks regarding your environment should be automatable and then the other teams can do the odd task that isn't.

This probably isn't the answer you were hoping for, but these are likely the challenges you'll have to tackle to get to your goal.

Comment: 1. Good point, but, in an ideal world, all the teams push code multiple times per day so that there aren't any big code changes that need integrating with each other?
2. I think there's always going to be an element of testing that involves more sensitive data, or heavier environments due to a lot of integration points, and there's always going to be some security team that's on top of that.
3. Teams are more component teams that work towards the same product, you're right.
4. Yes, we're talking about complicated systems because of many different components. So a maintenance team is needed.

Comment: Also, on CI, how do you keep track of changes for auditing purposes if everyone is pushing code all the time? Granted, that code will be against some Jira ticket, but are there any good practices documented on this subject?